# XOR 1 Byte (or Nibble) or Unsigned Char Hex array

Tags: c

I am attempting to create a random Bit Error with in a defined hex array. My idea is to XOR a random byte with 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 or 0x08, which should flip one bit in the signed char array. However I am having a lot of trouble printf'ing out my unsigned char array.

Even when I try a simple printf() I seem to be getting the element + 30. For example:

```
unsigned char randArray[] = "64F123C0";
printf("\nXor Value: %02x\n", randArray[2]);
```

Result: Xor Value: 46

This always seems to return the hex value converted to decimal (0x0F -> 16) added to 30. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to display 1 byte or 1 nibble from this unsigned char array?

anyway here is my code for the random error injection into a array of unsigned hex chars:

```
unsigned char randArray[] = "64F123C0";
unsigned char testXor[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08};

srand(time(0));

int randomError = 0;
int randomInjectNib = 0;


randomError = rand()%5;
randomInjectNib = rand()%8;

printf("\nThe Error Injected Byte is: %c and it was: %c\n\n", randArray[randomInjectNib]^testXor[randomError], randArray[randomInjectNib])
```

I am printing the %c here to becasue of the issue I was having with printing bytes from the array discussed above.

I would expect the results to look more like this:

```
unsigned char randArray[] = "64F123C0";
unsigned char testXor[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08};

printf("\nThe Error Injected Byte is: %c and it was: %c\n\n", randArray[2]^testXor[2], randArray[2])
```

Result: The Error Injected Byte is D and it was F

Comment: The ASCII value for `F` is 70 and you're just printing its hex equivalent. There is no `XOR` involved in your `printf`. To be honest your question is a bit terse in that it doesn't clearly points out what you're trying to do.

Comment: "64F123C0" is a string of [ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). From the linked table, you can see that the character '6' has hex value 0x36, '4' has hex value 0x34, and 'F` has value 0x46. So those are the numbers that you'll find in the array.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, is there a good way to convert that string off ASCII characters to a set of Bytes that I can perform Bit wise operations on?

Comment: something like `strtoul`?